# on_failure_callback is not working if I put it inside dag_default_args?

Tags: airflow

I found an inconsistent behavior when I tried to put on_failure_callback inside dag_default_args.
The following code works

```
#datetime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
import logging

def on_failure_callback(context):
    logging.error("enter on_failure_callback-----------")

# python callable function
def print_hello():
    raise Exception("helloworld exception")

with DAG(
    dag_id="hello_world_dag",
    default_args={
        'on_failure_callback': on_failure_callback,
    },
    schedule_interval="00 02 * * *",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 12, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:
    export = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        python_callable=print_hello,
        task_id="hello",
        dag=dag,
    )
```

However this code doesn't work

```
#datetime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
import logging

def on_failure_callback(context):
    logging.error("enter on_failure_callback-----------")

dag_default_args = {
    'retries': 1,
    'on_failure_callback': on_failure_callback,
}

# python callable function
def print_hello():
    raise Exception("helloworld exception")

with DAG(
    dag_id="hello_world_dag",
    default_args=dag_default_args,
    schedule_interval="00 02 * * *",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 12, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
) as dag:
    export = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        python_callable=print_hello,
        task_id="hello",
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Why the second is not working?

Comment: its related to  'retries': 1

Comment: The default `retry_delay` value is 300 seconds. Did you wait 5 minutes for the second instance to run and fail? I did and could see the `logging` message.

Comment: @ARCrow thanks, indeed I can see the failure log in the last retry, but why it is not triggered for the first run? is it working as design?

Comment: Yes. If you want a function to run before a retry, you can use the `on_retry_callback` option.